# Android: mount different userdata partition at boot

Tags: android, linux, mount, block-device

On my Samsung Note 10.1, I would like to be able to mount a different userdata partition. My goal is to achieve this at boot by modifying the `init.rc` script, since this seems to be setting up all file systems and mounting the partitions userdata, system, and so on. For example, there is a line `mkdir /data 0771 system system`, which sounds to me as if it sets up the mount point for the userdata partition. The userdata partition corresponds to block device `/dev/block/mmcblk0p12`.

Now, what I want is instead of mounting `mmcblk0p12`, I want to mount an image of `mmcblk0p12`, which I have placed on a µSD-Card inserted in the device. The µSD-Card is accessible via block device `/dev/block/vold/179:17`. This means that I would first need to mount the µSD-Card and then the image on the µSD-Card.

But this is where I fail. I can't figure out how to mount the µSD-Card in the `init.rc`, not to mention how to mount the image afterwards. I've added the line `mount -t ext4 /dev/block/vold/179\:17 /mnt/extSdCard` multiple times, but all it gives me is a boot loop.

So, does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT1: apparently the partitions get mounted in `fstab.sdmk4x12`, so I added the line `/dev/block/vold/179\:17 /mnt/extSdCard ext 4 noatime,nosuid,nodev,discard,noauto_da_alloc,journal_async_commit,erros=panic wait,check`. This unfortunately did not work, but kernel log gave me `Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/vold/179\:17 at /mnt/extSdCard`.

EDIT2: stupid of me not to use `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1`, which is the partition of the µSD-Card. This way I was now able to mount the µSD-Card by modifying the `fstab.sdmk4x12` file.

EDIT3: after I was able to mount the µSD-Card, the problem of how to mount the image remains. I've modified the line where it mounts the userdata partition. The line is the same as the one from EDIT1+2, but uses the image `/storage/extSdCard/userdata.img` to mount it to `/data`. But I guess it apparently fails to mount the image. The device boots up, but displays some error, stating the userdata partition is damaged. It also gives me the option to reset it, but of course this only affects the userdata partition, and as soon as I reboot, it is trying to mount my image again, fails and shows me this error again.

Comment: Perhaps [this could be of help](https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/android/f/509/t/224170) **or** [maybe this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/b4d65399fde02280b718e3b5b5cb1464a885c4b0/rootdir/init.rc)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Instead of trying to mount the image, I just copied all files from `/data` onto the partition on the µSD-Card, and mounted the partition as `/data` in the `fstab.sdmk4x12` (i.e., mounting `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1` as `/data`). All apps etc. will now be stored on the partition on the µSD-Card.